# string functions to find the corresponding close bracket for each open

Tags: python-3.x

I have a simple problem, which I hope you can help me resolve.

I have the two below lists. Opens shows the position of open brackets in a query and closes show the closing brackets.

I am trying so couple these together. Where I will end up with a list of lists.

Input

```
opens = [15, 39, 56]
closes = [44, 125, 150]
```

Desired output:

```
bracket_pairs = [[39,44], [15, 150], [56, 125]]
```

The input statement is:

```
sql = '''
select * from (
select date, hour, sum(size) as x from (
select date, hour, size from database.tablename
where dt = 20210101)tbl1
group by date, hour)tbl2
'''
```

SO the idea is, for each open position, we get the close position in the string.

I can't really think of a sensible way to do this

Can anyone help me

Here is what I tried, to get the inner pairs, at least. I now have an output where order = ['o', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'c'] (where 'F' means the pairs have been found).

I need to say, for each o, find the next c. This is harder when we have this, and the first o should relate to the last c
['o', 'o', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'c', 'c']

```
query = list(sql)
opens = []
closes = []

x = 0
while x < len(query):
    if query[x] == '(':
        opens.append(x)
    elif query[x] == ')':
        closes.append(x)
    x = x+1

joined = opens + closes
joined.sort()

#joined = [15, 39, 44, 55, 65, 77, 146, 171]

order = []

for n in joined:
    if n in opens:
        order.append('o')
    elif n in closes:
        order.append('c')

#order: ['o', 'o', 'c', 'o', 'c', 'o', 'c', 'c']

couples = []
        
x = 0
while x < len(order)-1:

    next_item = x+1

    if order[x] == 'o' and order[next_item] == 'c':
        couples.append([x, next_item])
        order[x] = 'F'
        order[next_item] = 'F'
    x = x+1
    
#couples: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the same logic as @Durtal's answer (it's easier to notice a closing bracket 'c' and pair it with the previous open 'o', than to find an 'o' and look for the next 'c' at the appropriate nesting depth); but using the lists you already have -

This will raise errors if any closing bracket appears before a corresponding open one (E.g- `"abc(def)gh)ijklm("`, so you can handle that by ignoring such closing brackets - they can't possibly be a part of any pair. Excess opening brackets won't create any errors - they just won't make their way to the final `pairs` list :

```py
opens = [15, 39, 56]     # These need not be sorted in any order
closes = [44, 125, 150]  # But should not contain duplicates

brackets = sorted(opens+closes)
# All bracket indices in the order as they appear

pairs = []
pending, unmatched = [], []
for pos in brackets:
    if pos in opens:
        pending.append(pos)
    else:
        try :
            pairs.append((pending.pop(-1), pos))
        except IndexError:
            unmatched.append(pos)
            continue
unmatched.extend(pending)
print(pairs, unmatched)
```

If you have to generate the `opens` and `closes` lists yourself, you can use the previous answer to look for brackets and match directly in the string, or add this to the start of my code

```py
string = input()
opens = [i for i, b in enumerate(string) if b=='(']
closes = [i for i, b in enumerate(string) if b==')']
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic, naive approach: Whenever you find `)` team it up with the last occurrence of `(` that has no partner yet. Catch Error when there were too few `(` up to this point.

```
sql = '''
select * from (
select date, hour, sum(size) as x from (
select date, hour, size from database.tablename
where dt = 20210101)tbl1
group by date, hour)tbl2
'''

def find_idxs_bracket(string):
    idxs_bracket_opened = []
    idxs_pairs = []
    for idx, char in enumerate(sql):
        if char == '(':
            idxs_bracket_opened.append(idx)
        if char == ')':
            try:
                idxs_pairs.append([idxs_bracket_opened[-1], idx])
                # delelte last ( from list of unmatched (
                idxs_bracket_opened = idxs_bracket_opened[:-1]
            except IndexError:
                return 'Error'
    if idxs_bracket_opened:
        return 'Error'
    return idxs_pairs

      
print(find_idxs_bracket(sql))
#[[39, 44], [56, 125], [15, 150]]
```

If you are interested what is inside those brackets, we might prefer a solution with regular expressions.